# Lambda function timeout metric in cloudwatch

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a metric emitted when a lambda function times out? I want to setup an alarm if my lambda times out (i.e. runs longer than 15 minutes) but I can't find any timeout related metrics in the cloudwatch console

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the maximum timeout you can set on a lambda function is 15 minutes, but the timeout on the lambda function can occur at any time, depending on the timeout value you've configured for your lambda function.

When a timeout occurs, Lambda will log the following message in CloudWatch:

```
2023-09-01T17:42:26.164Z 89bd67db-004a-4044-b906-1853229b3aa9 Task timed out after 15.02 seconds
```

Since **there are no built-in metrics for lambda timeouts**, you need to create your own metric based on the log pattern. For instance, to filter the timeout events from the log group, you can use this filter pattern `Task timed out`

To create a metric filter from the CloudWatch log group, refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CreateMetricFilterProcedure.html) AWS documentation.

Once you have the metric filter for timeout events, it becomes easy for you to set up the CloudWatch alarm.